# Kubernetes metrics-server unable to fully scrape metrics

Tags: kubernetes

When I try to use `kubectl top nodes` I get this error:

```
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource (get services http:heapster:)
```

But heapster is deprecated and I'm using kubernetes 1.11. I installed metrics-server and I still get the same error, when I try to check metrics-server's logs I see this error:

```
E1019 12:33:55.621691       1 manager.go:102] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:elegant-ardinghelli-ei3: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet elegant-ardinghelli-ei3 (elegant-ardinghelli-ei3):
Get https://elegant-ardinghelli-ei3:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup elegant-ardinghelli-ei3 on 10.245.0.10:53: no such host, unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:elegant-ardinghelli-aab: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet elegant-ardinghelli-aab (elegant-ardinghelli-aab):
Get https://elegant-ardinghelli-aab:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup elegant-ardinghelli-aab on 10.245.0.10:53: no such host, unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:elegant-ardinghelli-e4z: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet elegant-ardinghelli-e4z (elegant-ardinghelli-e4z):
Get https://elegant-ardinghelli-e4z:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup elegant-ardinghelli-e4z on 10.245.0.10:53: no such host, unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:elegant-ardinghelli-e41: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet elegant-ardinghelli-e41 (elegant-ardinghelli-e41):
Get https://elegant-ardinghelli-e41:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup elegant-ardinghelli-e41 on 10.245.0.10:53: no such host, unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:elegant-ardinghelli-ein: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet elegant-ardinghelli-ein (elegant-ardinghelli-ein): 
Get https://elegant-ardinghelli-ein:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup elegant-ardinghelli-ein on 10.245.0.10:53: no such host, unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:elegant-ardinghelli-aar: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet elegant-ardinghelli-aar (elegant-ardinghelli-aar):
Get https://elegant-ardinghelli-aar:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup elegant-ardinghelli-aar on 10.245.0.10:53: no such host, unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:elegant-ardinghelli-aaj: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet elegant-ardinghelli-aaj (elegant-ardinghelli-aaj):
Get https://elegant-ardinghelli-aaj:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup elegant-ardinghelli-aaj on 10.245.0.10:53: no such host, unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:elegant-ardinghelli-e49: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet elegant-ardinghelli-e49 (elegant-ardinghelli-e49):
Get https://elegant-ardinghelli-e49:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup elegant-ardinghelli-e49 on 10.245.0.10:53: no such host]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is reported here.

Github Issues:

> This PR implements support for the kubectl top commands to use the
>   metrics-server as an aggregated API, instead of requesting the metrics
>   from heapster directly. If the metrics.k8s.io API is not served by the
>   apiserver, then this still falls back to the previous behavior.

Merged in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/56206

Maybe fixed in 1.12 or scheduled for next version.

Comment: output of kubectl version
`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.3", GitCommit:"a4529464e4629c21224b3d52edfe0ea91b072862", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-09-10T11:45:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.11", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.1", GitCommit:"b1b29978270dc22fecc592ac55d903350454310a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-07-17T18:43:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`
Same error using --namespace=kube-system

Comment: API server can connect to metric server ? did you check the metrics server deployment , decsribe and logs

Comment: logs from the metrics-server gives the unable to fully collect metrics: error that I wrote in the question, describe gives this https://ghostbin.com/paste/w66jg